# samba + kerberos ssh single signon (SSO)

Tags: ssh, samba, kerberos, single-sign-on

I'm modifying an existing samba config that it works fine for authenticating AD users on linux servers to also handle Kerberos and SSO.

I've successfully got pam_winbind to use kerberos and it is handing out tickets, as well as having configured SSH to allow GSSAPI and Kerberos.

Unfortunately though, when attempting to login via PuTTY using SSO, it fails.

Is anyone who is familiar with configuring this able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working now by following the guide [here](http://michele.pupazzo.org/diary/?p=475).

A few caveats;

- you need the dev release of putty
- you apparently need to go in via the dns
  name of the host